# How to set an if statement if a canvas object reaches a certain coordinate? tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm making a snake game with tkinter and I'm trying to print out a 'game over' message if the snake touches the window. How do I do this?

Here's what I've gotten so far:

```py
from tkinter import *
# import random, disregard random module, unused

def up(event):
    canvas.move(snakebody, 0, -20)

def down(event):
    canvas.move(snakebody, 0, 20)

def left(event):
    canvas.move(snakebody, -20, 0)

def right(event):
    
    canvas.move(snakebody, 20, 0)

# root
window = Tk()

window.config(bg='darkgreen')
window.geometry('450x450')
window.resizable(0, 0)

# canvas
canvas = Canvas(window, bg='darkgreen', borderwidth=0)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# snake body/head
snakebody = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 50, 50, 100, outline='lightgreen', fill='lightgreen')

# game over message
if canvas.coords(snakebody) == canvas.coords(snakebody, 50, 50, 100, 100):
    print('game over')

# control binds
window.bind('<Up>', up)
window.bind('<Down>', down)
window.bind('<Left>', left)
window.bind('<Right>', right)

window.mainloop()
```

please help

Comment: I guess the best approach would be to use `enclosed(x1,y1,x2,y2)` because it will only show items in the canvas that are completely in this boundary. Then you just have to check if your snake is within this array of items. But you lack a little bit of context for a code answer.

Comment: Something in your application is moving the snake, so that is where you should put the statement.

Comment: @Thingamabobs, should it be `canvas.enclosed()` then? And what arguments should be inside `enclosed()`, the same arguments I put in `canvas.coords()`?

Comment: @FellowProgrammer Where should I know, since I don't know what's behind these variables. As I said, your question has a lack of details.

Comment: @Thingamabobs, sorry, I've edited my code. Hope you can answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's too early for your question. You will need to answer different questions before. Your movement never allows you that the snake *bites* itself. Nor will your snake move around a corner. Because of that it's most likely that you have to change that function. Anyway to show you the concept of what I mentioned in the comment section.

I have implemented a function that is called `after_tick()`. Inside of the function I defined the boundery from (0,0) = upper left corner and the maximum coord in width and height by asking the canvas for its property. After that I ask the canvas for the items inside of this *box* and if the id of `snakebody` is not inside, print *game over*.

Additional suggestions:

- implement a function `tick`, a tick is usually the next step in a automation
- use multiple rectangles for your snake and use tags for the head and the body
- dont use wildcard imports to avoid name conflicts

```
from tkinter import *

def after_tick():
    max_w = canvas.winfo_width()
    max_h = canvas.winfo_height()
    in_cnvs = canvas.find_enclosed(0,0,max_w,max_h)
    if snakebody not in in_cnvs:
        print('game over')    

def move_event(event):
    key = str(event.keysym)
    if key == 'Up':
        canvas.move(snakebody, 0, -20)
    elif key == 'Down':
        canvas.move(snakebody, 0, 20)
    elif key == 'Left':
        canvas.move(snakebody, -20, 0)
    elif key == 'Right':
        canvas.move(snakebody, 20, 0)
    after_tick()


window = Tk()
window.config(bg='darkgreen')
window.geometry('450x450')
window.resizable(0, 0)

canvas = Canvas(window, bg='darkgreen', borderwidth=0)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

snakebody = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 50, 50, 100,
                                    outline='lightgreen',
                                    fill='lightgreen')

window.bind('<Up>', move_event)
window.bind('<Down>', move_event)
window.bind('<Left>', move_event)
window.bind('<Right>', move_event)

window.mainloop()
```