# Make canvas object move up and down tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

How would you go about moving a canvas rectangle up and down in tkinter without it leaving the screen? The purpose of this (in my case) is to create a "ai" paddle that goes against a player. the opposing paddle is rightPong btw. Thoughts?

```
import tkinter as tk

ypong = 0

pongMovement = 0


def keyup(e):
    global pongMovement
    global pongEdit
    global Pong
    if pongMovement > 0:
        pongMovement = pongMovement - 10
        pongEdit.place(x=1, y=pongMovement)
        pongEdit.update()


def keydown(e):
    global pongMovement
    global pongEdit
    global Pong
    if pongMovement < 500:
        pongMovement = pongMovement + 10
        pongEdit.place(x=1, y=pongMovement)
        pongEdit.update()


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('600x600')
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.bind('<Up>', keyup)
window.bind('<Down>', keydown)

pongEdit = tk.Canvas(window, width=10, height=100, bg="black")
Pong = pongEdit.create_rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20, fill="red")
pongEdit.pack()

pongEdit.place(x=1, y=pongMovement)

rightpongEdit = tk.Canvas(window, width=10, height=100, bg="black")
rightPong = pongEdit.create_rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20, fill="red")
rightpongEdit.pack(side='right')




window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Look into this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71909632/how-to-set-an-if-statement-if-a-canvas-object-reaches-a-certain-coordinate-tkin/71911639#71911639

Comment: Is this question similar to your another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74538852/stop-canvas-from-leaving-frame-tkinter)?

Comment: Normally `Canvas` is used as the only container for all the game items, not an item in a canvas.  Then you can use canvas function to move those game items inside the canvas.